# enable https for hue on hadoop

Tags: hadoop, ssl, https, hue

After reading the documentation, I thought this would be easy and straight forward but it's not working at all.

I have generated a 2048-bit key and self-signed it. They are in the locations that hue.ini is pointing to:

```
# Filename of SSL Certificate
ssl_certificate=/etc/hue/certs/cert/server.crt
# Filename of SSL RSA Private Key
ssl_private_key=/etc/hue/certs/key/server.key

# Webserver listens on this address and port
http_host=0.0.0.0
http_port=8082
```

So when I /etc/init.d/hue restart, the service appears to start fine. I cannot browse over http or https to the hue URL.

When I comment out the key and cert line and restart, I can browse hue on http port 8082 just fine.

Do I need to change http_port to 443? I tried that with no luck. I also tried to browse https://secret.url:8082 with no luck.

I have opened port 443 and 8082 in iptables for https and http respectively. I can see the packet count go up when I fail the test. So the network firewall appears to be open on the right ports.

I seem to be missing something. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Aside from certificate generation, is there some switch that turns on https that I'm not seeing mentioned in the documentation? Do I need a GUI to get to some kind of control panel (yast) to enable https? I'm using command line only.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The certificate needs the CN for the domain name, of course. I found a one-liner to self-sign a cert with CN added in.

It's in the comments of this post: https://major.io/2007/08/02/generate-self-signed-certificate-and-key-in-one-line/#comment-1937883918